# MySQL "Field Like Array" Functionality

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like:

```
SELECT ID FROM SomeTable WHERE ZipCode IN (SELECT Zip FROM SomeOtherTable)
```

This works as expected, however I need have a LIKE command.  Some US zip codes are XXXXX-XXXX.  I need the statement to match the first 5 characters only, even if it has more.

My PHP zip code check is:

```
preg_match("/^([0-9]{5})(-[0-9]{4})?$/i",$zip_code)
```

to show the format of how the zips are checked to be stored.

I have read about there being no IN LIKE command and to use REGEXP, but I am not sure how to use REGEXP with a select statement.

How would I go about changing this MySQL statement to match zips by the first 5 characters only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the query to:

```
SELECT ID FROM SomeTable WHERE SUBSTR(ZipCode,0,5) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(Zip,0,5) FROM SomeOtherTable)
```

By the way, if SomeOtherTable has more than one record per zip code, you may be able to speed things up by adding **DISTINCT** to the inner query so it produces just a unique list of zip codes. See [the SELECT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Comment: Looks like it should work, but the substr and substring don't return anything for some reason.  It returns a row, but it's blank.  I tried to make it easy SELECT SUBSTR(Zip,0,5) FROM SomeOtherTable and it returns a bunch of blank results.  I tried changing Zip to something text value like "zipcode" and still nothing.

Comment: `SUBSTR` isn't zero based.  Try `SUBSTR(ZipCode,1,5)`

Answer (score 0):

LEFT or RIGHT as used at the end of this tutorial - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-like-mysql.aspx

Comment: Can't figure out how to implement this.  It's straight forward with 1 value, but not sure how to do it with a select statement.